# How to use hook_pre_build depending on what time of day it is?

Tags: views, datetime

I need some help with the hook_pre_build hook in views. I am trying to set the image link on an image to off depending on what time of day it is and I cannot seem to find the syntax to change that fields settings.

I have searched a lot trying to find the right way to change this at this step and it is not working for me, any help?

```
function uc_custom_process_views_pre_build(&$view) {
$current_day = date('N');
$current_time =  date('Gi');
$open = 1600;
$results = &$view->result;
if ($view->name == 'uc_catalog') {
    foreach($results as $key => $result){       
        $result->field['uc_product_image']->options['settings']['image_link'] ='';
    }
    if($current_time < $open){
        unset($view->field['buyitnowbutton']);
    }
    else{
        foreach($view->result as $r){
            $closes_at = $r->field_closes_at;   
            if (($closes_at < $current_time)||($current_time < $open)){
                    unset($view->field['buyitnowbutton']);
                    $r->display_options['fields']['uc_product_image']['settings']['image_link'] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```